# jQuery - Count items (using .length) for validator not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate a minimum of 4 photos uploaded in a gallery using jQuery.

The gallery looks like this: https://ibb.co/XsTd84w

I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#submit-listing-form").submit(function(){
    
        var validador = 0;
        var cantidad = jQuery('#media-uploader').find('.dz-preview').length;
        if (cantidad => 4) {
                validador++;
            }
            
        if (validador){
            jQuery('.validacionminimoimagenes').html();
        }else{
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery("#gallery_forScroll").offset().top
            }, 2000);
            jQuery('.validacionminimoimagenes').html('Debes subir al menos 4 imagenes.');
            return false;
        }
        
    });
});
```

However, this is not working.

I think its a problem with the count of photos (im using .length for this).

Can someone guide me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's not working? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Syntax error: `=>` should be `>=`

Comment: It should show me the error message if I don't upload 4 or more images in the gallery

Comment: @Barmar that was the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Barmer has pointed. Let me explain for beginners. Always put `<` and `>` before `=`. Just write the symbols in order when you pronounce words. For example,

- `LESS THAN or EQUAL TO` will be written like `<=`
- `GREATER THAN or EQUAL TO` will be written like `>=`